# В режиме монитора встроеный адаптер не находит сети. black box linux

Tags: linux, сеть, wifi

При сканировании сетей в wifite не находит сетей. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Поиск в гугле ничего не дал.

Comment: звучит так, что адаптер просто не умеет работать в режиме монитора... чтобы подтвердить — см. в гугле опыт коллег с этим чипом